# "spde.build:sdl-pack:22.+" error in importing project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, import

When I am trying to import a project in android studio , I am getting the following error window:

"Could not find any version that matches spde.build:sdl-pack:22.+. Searched in the following locations:
//some location in program files folder 
"

Has anyone faced this issue earlier?
What can I do to solve this issue?